# Button click event submits the quantity

Tags: angular

This question is related to another question that I asked recently at the forum. I had to start a new post because my question evolved over time and my original question wasn't valid any more. I narrowed down my problem to the quantity buttons submitting every time they're clicked so I am only showing my quantity button code. What I want to find out is how can I get the buttons to only submit when the submit button is clicked. Right now they console log 'click submitted' every time they are clicked.

The HTML

```
<button class="minus-btn" (click)="minus(product)" type="button" name="btn" onclick="return false;">
<img src="../assets/images/minus.svg" alt="minus" /></button>
<input class="num" name="int" [value]="product.nullValue" formControlName="int" ng-minlength="0" type="number" required />
<button class="plus-btn" (click)="plus($event, product)" name="btn" type="button" onclick="return false;">
<img src="../assets/images/plus.svg" alt="plus" /></button>
```

and in the controller:

```
plus($event, product:any) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  product.nullValue++;
  this.quantity = product.nullValue;
  console.log('click submitted');
  return false;  
  return this.quantity;
 
}

minus(product:any){ 
 product.nullValue--;
  this.quantity = product.nullValue;
  console.log('click submitted'); 
  return false;
  return this.quantity;

}
```

The problem is in the pipe that I created. It gets the quantity multiple times and this is reflected in the sub_total that gets returned.

```
@Pipe({name: 'grandtotal'})

export class GrandTotalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  
  sub_total = 0;
  product_price = 0;
  quantity = 0;
  total = 0;
  transform(product_price: number, quantity: number, sub_total: number) {
    sub_total = product_price * quantity;
    sub_total += sub_total;
        return sub_total; 
    
  }
}
```

I call the pipe in the HTML with the following:

```
<div>Grand Total {{ product_price | grandtotal:  quantity : sub_total }}</div>
```

Comment: both your methods has `console.log('click submitted')`. what do you expect?

Comment: Both of your buttons have a bound method to a `(click)` event, and both of those methods log `'click submitted'`. Seems like an expected behavior to me. The buttons aren't submitting anything, they just call those methods when you click

Comment: The problem is that the click event updates the quantity before the form is submitted. This results in multiple quantities being submitted and the logic handling the quantities fails.

Comment: I don't see many problems with the code itself, but what I still don't understand is what is the desired behavior. Do you want to submit the form before updating the quantity? PS you have an unreachable `return` statement, which I'll assume stayed there by accident.

Comment: I edited the question to show the problem.

Comment: I still feel like this is not enough info. It really depends how and what you pass to the pipe transform, which is not shown in your current question code. Maybe this will help: Pipes are stateless by default, so initialization lines like: `sub_total = 0;` are useless. Your currently implemented `transform` method is [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm), it will always give the same output given the same input. Its output, also, **only** depends on the input given. If you want, you can add code where you call the pipe, I'm still following the question.

Comment: I edited my question to show how the pipe is called in the HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218287/discussion-between-maureen-moore-and-pajle).